# Gnome 3.12 - Choppy Animations with Intel HD 4600 Graphics

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics

I've just purchased a Lenovo T540p and installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.10. So far, the performance of Gnome Shell has been very sub par. Animations like opening the activities overview or moving windows around from within the overview are choppy.

I have looked into various methods of resolving these issues like changing the `AccelMethod` to `uxa` or `glamor` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, but nothing has changed the perfomance at all. I have also tried disabling vsync using `.drirc`.

Most recently I tried using [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) to update by drivers, but the lag still prevailed.

Currently everything is back to default. Any ideas on how to resolve this lag issue?

**Driver**: i915 
**Kernel**: 3.16.0-24-generic

---

**EDIT**

Turns out this lag issue is caused by the Intel HD 4600 Integrated Graphics not being fully supported in Ubuntu (Linux in general?). The graphics performance is fine when resolution is set to 1920x1080, but not when set to 2880x1620.

Comment: Kernel? Driver?

Comment: What grpahics and drivers are you using (you can use `lspci -v`)

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I found the output of `inxi -SMIG -! 31` much more friendly and useful.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [last video drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037682/349837)

  ```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
  ```
- Disable [showing seconds on clock](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071199/349837)

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds false
  ```
- Disable animations in [GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076642/349837) (or in [Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/68393/349837)). [Using CLI](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067791/349837):

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
  ```