# Nvidia binaries - odd login procedure

Tags: nvidia

This [Black screen on login, gnome-shell eating 100% of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/q/1079872/19559)

has the same symptoms I have.

I can login with nvidia-drivers if I

- recovery console at grub
- make filesystem writeable
- resume to gui login
- switch to tty 4  after login screen is visible
- login on tty4
- Switch back to gui login on tty1
- login is possible

How do I debug this? There is nothing useful in the text logs.

The dupe has no valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help, but there's no need to go through recovery console.
You can boot up to login screen, SSH to your computer and run `systemctl isolate multi-user.target; systemctl isolate graphical.target` to get the same result.
Yes, it is not a solution, but maybe it will help you narrowing possible ways of debugging.