# Sluggish/Laggy Ubuntu - gnome-shell too much CPU

Tags: gnome, 18.04, virtualbox, cpu, guest-additions

it started off from super sluggish behaviour on my Ubuntu 18.04 VB on Windows 10 Host. I updated and upgraded all of the packages. Updated Windows. Grepped for errors in syslog. And then I noticed that `gnome-shell` is spiking to 100% or more (not sure how that's possible) CPU usage on all CPUs from time to time. I stumbled upon [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036441/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage) post. Which offers to do `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, which when I do, I get the following:

[image]

**Tried a fresh new install. Same problem (also conflicts for guest additions. Puring does not help. That error is still there). I have also noticed something interesting, which I believe is a by-product of this conflict. Upon running `inxi -b`:**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: How many CPU cores did you give to the VM?  How many CPU cores are on your computer?  How much RAM did you give the VM?

Comment: I gave it 4. it's i7-7700HQ, so 4 cores. 10GB, laptop has 16 GB RAM

Comment: 3d Acceleration is disabled

Comment: I have same sluggish behaviour when I use cinnamon desktop on my ubuntu, or I simply make a fresh install of Ubuntu (still sluggish + still conflict of guest additions). Same problem if I install elementaryOS. It sounds like a problem with a host. But I can see that my graphics driver is working allright.