# gnome-shell high cpu usage with disabled extensions

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am aware of the similar sounding question: [Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell high CPU usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036441/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage)

However my issue is a bit different, since it is not related to the mouse/ clock/animations because I deactivated all of those features and did not move the mouse and still could observe my issue: 
If I disable gnome-extensions completely via gnome-tweak-tools the following happens with my idle CPU usage of gnome-shell:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: 10%
- Reboot: 0%-2%

Why is there a difference between a reboot and gnome-shell replace?

If I don't disable gnome-extension as such but deactivate every extension the following happens with the idle CPU usage of gnome-shell:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: 10%
- Reboot: 10%

Why is there a such a big difference between disabling all extensions and the extension functionality itself?

The CPU usage of gnome-shell is taken when everything was idle (no mouse movement/ no seconds in clock/ no animation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell high CPU usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036441/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage)

Comment: @PabloBianchi as I stated in the first sentence of the post I am aware of the referred question. However my problem does not match any of the answers and is different in detail

Comment: In both cases is not clear the source of the CPU usage by gnome-shell process. FMPV they are the same question. If **current** answers do not satisfy your case is not enough reason to create another question. BTW you are asking several questions which is not a good practice.