# When I lock my PC, the fans get very noisy as if there was some kind of a rogue process

Tags: gnome-terminal, lock-screen, cpu-load, gnome-session

The moment I lock my PC, the fans get really noisy, which means there has to be some kind of CPU/GPU load behind the scenes.

I told myself, I need to know, what process is doing this, so I've crafted this audit script using `top` and `awk`, which basically takes `*.csv` filename as input and writes there every second 10 most demanding processes.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SLEEP_SECS=1

DESTFILE="$1"
if ! [[ "${DESTFILE}" =~ \.csv$ ]]; then
        echo "Please provide name of a destination .csv file!"
        exit 1
fi

if ! test -f "${DESTFILE}"; then
        echo "Seconds;PID;User;% CPU;Process Name" > "${DESTFILE}" || exit $?
fi

while true; do
        top -b -o %CPU -n1 | \
                tail -n +8 | \
                head -10 | \
                awk '{print systime() ";" $1 ";" $2 ";" $9 ";" $12}' \
                >> "${DESTFILE}" || exit $?
        echo -n .
        sleep "${SLEEP_SECS}"
done
```

So I've started the script and locked my screen, fans got really noisy, I waited a little, logged back in, fans got quiet (as if they knew I don't want them to be noisy when I'm not doing anything with the PC :D ) and I've looked into the processes, which got more than 50% of the CPU usage with this command:

```bsh
gawk --use-lc-numeric -F';' '{if($4 > 50) {print $0}}' cpu-audit.csv
```

Here's what I've found:

```
# The header wasn't there OFC, I'm including it just for the convenience
  Seconds ; PID;  User  ;% CPU;Process Name
1566804437;2496;jirislav;106,7;gnome-shell
1566804438;2496;jirislav;106,7;gnome-shell
1566804439;2496;jirislav;100,0;gnome-shell
1566804440;2496;jirislav;100,0;gnome-shell
1566804442;2496;jirislav;93,8;gnome-shell
1566804443;2496;jirislav;100,0;gnome-shell
1566804444;2496;jirislav;100,0;gnome-shell
1566804445;2496;jirislav;100,0;gnome-shell
1566804446;2496;jirislav;106,7;gnome-shell
1566804449;2496;jirislav;131,2;gnome-shell
1566804449;17446;jirislav;68,8;nautilus
```

What a surprise, `gnome-shell` was demanding so much resources? What the ...?! I'm not even using it, I use `terminator` all the time. Ok, so I ran the terminal audit using `ps`, but it haven't detected the usage as the `top` did, why not? I'm even listing all the child processes:

```
$ while true; do ps fu --ppid 2496 --pid 2496; sleep 1; done
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jirislav  2496  7.3  2.2 2949284 357176 tty2   Rl+  08:49   3:02 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
jirislav  2522  0.7  0.0 322108  8800 tty2     Sl   08:49   0:18  \_ ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
jirislav  3239  1.2  0.4 855328 67956 tty2     Sl+  08:49   0:30  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/terminato
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jirislav  2496  7.3  2.2 2949284 356820 tty2   Sl+  08:49   3:02 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
jirislav  2522  0.7  0.0 322108  8800 tty2     Sl   08:49   0:18  \_ ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
jirislav  3239  1.2  0.4 855328 67956 tty2     Sl+  08:49   0:30  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/terminato
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jirislav  2496  7.3  2.2 2949284 356820 tty2   Rl+  08:49   3:03 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
jirislav  2522  0.7  0.0 322108  8800 tty2     Sl   08:49   0:18  \_ ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
jirislav  3239  1.2  0.4 855328 67956 tty2     Sl+  08:49   0:30  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/terminato
```

---

I said enough, let's uninstall `gnome-shell`, I'm not even using it, why let it consume the resources and run noisy fans without my consent? .. Then it hit me, `gnome-shell` cannot be uninstalled without also uninstalling `ubuntu-desktop` - let's put aside the question why there is this weird dependency, which doesn't make sense (it could use any other terminal) - the thing I'm wandering about is - **what is Ubuntu doing while my session is locked and can I turn this off**?

When I'm on meeting, it's really inconvenient.

#### Note:

I know about the question [Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell high CPU usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036441/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage), but none of the proposed solutions work (not that I even expected them to work, because the issue is that mine `gnome-shell` is using too much resources only when I lock the PC - not when I use it as the linked question describes)

Comment: This may be unrelated, but on XFCE I had similar high usage (mostly disk) when I didn't expect it; for me i eventually tracked down to thumbnails being created for my mounted directories with tons of photos etc. Disabling the display of them hushed mine (though I eventually re-enabled it so it built the thumbnail cache when I didn't mind disk activity & fan-noise which soon resulted for me; once thumb-nail cache was created it disappeared).  fyi: you didn't give your release, but gnome-shell is expected in ubuntu-desktop in 18.04 & 19.04

Comment: Why ps is not the right tool: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result . Also gnome-shell is the default ubuntu-desktop, so if you are using vanilla Ubuntu, you are using it. Unfortunately, this does sound like a bug.

Comment: @guiverc I'm sorry I didn't mention this, but my release is Disco Dingo - 19.04. And I'm running it on MSI GS75 9SF (gaming machines are noisy when under heavy load). @Bruni that explains why `ps` outputs different usage than `top`, thank you. How can I confirm that this is a bug?

Comment: I have same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with Thinkpad P51, gnome shell 3.28.4

Comment: *similar issue. not the exact same

Comment: `top -b -i` can be used to show the non-idle tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Looks like it's a bug with [the nVidia driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1814125). The problem vanished after I installed the latest open-source nVidia driver:

```bsh
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, but then it broke again in v460!  455 is no longer an option displayed for Ubuntu 20.10