# Ubuntu 20.04: CPU usage peaks every 10 seconds - must be gnome-shell

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, cpu

I upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 a few weeks ago. Since then I am experiencing peaks of full CPU usage every 10 seconds. My Computer literally freezes for about a second. Here's a graph that shows what I mean: https://media-cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/52/34/9182809-auslastung_gnome-shell.png

Typing or scrollig sucks but watching videos is almost impossible.

I can see that gnome-shell is responsible for it, but I don't know what causes it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ```top``` to see exactly what is causing it.  Can also see this link if gnome shell is the problem.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036441/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage?rq=1

Comment: Alt+F2 to open run dialogue and then press 'r' to restart gnome-shell. Hope it helps.

Comment: "top" result when CPU usage peaks: gnome-shell = 66,7 %

Comment: restarting gnome-shell sadly didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I turned my Wi-fi connection off and strangely everything worked fine. Turns out that MEGAsync, a cloud software, somehow causes gnome-shell to use all of my CPU's capacity. I reported a bug.
So this is not a "solution" to the problem, but a workaround.