# Faster app menu in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, appmenu, animations

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and one of my first negative impressions is the long animation of flying-in icons when opening the app menu.

Can I speed this up or disable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

[This link shows you how](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/disable-gnome-shell-animation-on-ubuntu-1710-and-1804.html)

The link shows you how to turn off all kind of animations especially the spreading icons on menu, searching, and window animations so you can work faster. To do it, just run this command:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Then apply it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type  <kbd>r</kbd>  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will reset the GNOME Shell to follow your command.

To revert it back (enable animation again), just change the command to:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on Ask Ubuntu. Adding the main steps required to solve the issue would greatly improve the answer and probably help earn some magical rep points.

Comment: @Arronical Post amended as suggested to include the essential elements of the link.

Answer (score 12):

If you're annoyed by only the "*Show Applications*" animation, you can disable it by running the following in Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock animate-show-apps false
```

If you want to get rid of all the GNOME shell animations, run the following instead

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

You can also speed up GNOME shell animations following this: [How do I change the speed of the app drawer appearing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971260/how-do-i-change-the-speed-of-the-app-drawer-appearing)

Comment: This should be the solution to OPs request, as it disables only the animation when opening the app menu. Most solutions disable *all* animations and leave you with a desktop experience from the early 2000s.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock animate-show-apps false` does not work